# Android // dialog box is not visible after intent.createChooser see a black screen

Tags: android

**dialog box is not visible after intent.createChooser see a black screen.**

and Is turned off and the power button, the dialog box appears..

The problem occurs on version 2.3 and 4.0 (ics) working normally.

Anyone have any ideas?...

Comment: can you please post your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try do next:
on some button click insert next code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setTitle("Title");
                builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
```

It's NOT solution, just try. To checkout if it's not works. So you must search problem this way.